# Can we call a servlet or java method from mysql trigger.?

Tags: mysql, servlets, triggers

Is it possible to call a `servlet` by writing a trigger in MySQL.

Whenever there is a new record inserted into the table, I want to call another application by invoking `jsp`, `servlet` or `java`.

Comment: whenever there is new record is insert in table , i wanted to call another application by invoking jsp , servlet or java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other ways,
we can do that.
i have searched for this in Google but can't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is only one way - use [UDFs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html), which are user defined functions that allow invoking functions in external libraries.

Otherwise, you need to review database/application logic.

Comment: can you send send me any link of UDF's examples , how they can call external library functions.

Comment: Currently I do not have this library, but you can find them in internet, once we were finding them and steps to apply.

Comment: okay...thanks @Devart,
i will search that on internet. but still
whenever you find something on this,
kindly let me know.

Comment: is there any other way we can call another application ?

Comment: MySQL does not provide another way.